# apk is installed but not working on android 6.0 version only xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am developing my android app using xamarin forms. The Released apk install on even Android 5.1.1 and above Android 6.0.1 version is working fine.

But When i installed on Android 6.0, it is installed. But when i open the app, this shows 'The App is unfortunately Closed' error.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try to read logs, or add for example AppCenter for crash reporting.

Comment: Maybe on app start you are doing stuff that requires permissions that you have not given

Comment: My android App is Builded successfully only when i check the "Use Shared Runtime" in release mode. When i uncheck "Use Shared Runtime", then error show like "The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly" while Build the project. I think "Use Shared Runtime" is the problem...